# Failure to transfer failsafe-maven-plugin - Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, nexus

My service have Nexus Sonatype, in down my apache, run with HTTPS, but my certificator was not valid, when run

```
mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

for cmd Windows it's ok, but for Eclipse in pom.xml has red with this message m2e

> Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:pom:2.4.3-alpha-1 from 
>   my:URL was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
>   interval of public has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
>   Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:pom:2.4.3-alpha-1 from/to 
>   public my:URL: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

when run same comand for Eclipse this error out

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:2.4.3-alpha-1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access public (https://myURL/nexus/content/repositories/public/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:jar:2.4.3-alpha-1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:2.4.3-alpha-1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access public (https://myURL/nexus/content/repositories/public/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.mojo:failsafe-maven-plugin:jar:2.4.3-alpha-1 has not been downloaded from it before.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)




final stacktrace Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.RepositoryOfflineException: Cannot access public(https: //myURL/nexus/content/repositories/public/) in offline mode
```

my signture htpps create for me, but i'm test devolupment.

can help me with this problema

Comment: The plugin is named: [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) with it's groupId: `org.apache.maven.plugins` and **NOT**  `failsafe-maven-plugin`...

Answer (score 0):

The solution found this,

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>failsafe-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3-alpha-1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```